# question about closure in javascript with an example

Tags: javascript, closures

there

In a word,I'm confused about the difference between 
`handler.getName()` and
`function(){handler.getName()}`

For more detail,Please seet the code:

[Jsfiddle checking url](http://jsfiddle.net/lanston/KcaZe/)


My Question is :
while I use **obj.method** ,the **this** can refer to **handler** and 
while I use **obj.method2**, the **this** refer to **obj** 
I know this is something about closure,But I just don't know how to explain such things
Hope someone can help,Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not only about closures, it's also about what `this` refers to inside a function. [MDN has a good article about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are calling directly the method `getName` of the handler object, in the second one, you practically did a shallow copy of the function into the `obj` object, so when you call it will run the same code but use the local `names` attribute, so you get `"obj"`. If you would delete the `names` in the `obj` object, the value would be undefined. It has nothing to do with closures, you just copied the contents of a function into a new object method, and the `this` in that function will refer to the new host object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in your code is not what you think it is.  In .method, you do this:

```
handler.getName()
```

In .method2 you do:

```
handler.getName
```

If you change method2 to be:

```
handler.getName()
```

You will see that the results are the same for method and method2.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is called as a method on an object then *this* refers to the
object:

```
var x = {
    a: 1,
    f: function() {return this.a;}
};
document.write(x.f());   // writes 1
```

After entering *obj.method()*, *this* refers to *obj* (try to add 
the statement *document.write(this.names)* before *handler.getName()*.) 
 Then *getName()* is
called on *handler*, such that *this* refers to 
*handler* inside *handler.getName()*.

The function *handler.getName* was only assigned to *obj.method2*, not yet called and *this* 
is not yet bound. When *obj.method2()* is called, then *this* is bound to *obj* inside *method2()*.

You can also try in the global scope:

```
var f = handler.getName;
f();  // now window.names = "the window" is written
```